# how to get column index in a multicolumn div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a multicolumn div and need to get the column index of a clicked element.

```js
$('.child').click(function() {
    let a = $(this).column().index();
    let b = $(this).column().children().length;
    let c = $(this).index(/*relative to a column*/);
});
```

```css
.parent{
column-count:3;
}

.child{
cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='parent'>
<div class='child'>lorem</div>
<div class='child'>lorem</div>
<div class='child'>lorem</div>
<div class='child'>lorem</div>
<div class='child'>lorem</div>
<div class='child'>lorem</div>
<div class='child'>lorem</div>
<div class='child'>lorem</div>
</div>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Example 1

`Math.ceil(b.children().length / b.css('column-count'))`: divide the number of children, by the number of columns (as per the `class="parent"` CSS value for `column-count`. Then use `Math.ceil()` to round the number up.

`d = 0` and `e = false` are used by the following `while () {}` loop. Inside the loop, `d` gets incremented each loop, and `a` is reduced by `c`. This continues until `a` is less than 0. Then the loop is finished, and the `console.log()` prints the value (to the log).

```js
$('.child').click(function() {
  let a = $(this).index();
  let b = $(this).parent();
  let c = Math.ceil(b.children().length / b.css('column-count'));

  let d = 0;
  let e = false;

  while (!e) {
    d += 1;
    a = a - c;
    if (a < 0) {
      e = true;
    };
  };

  console.log(d)
});
```

```css
.parent {
  column-count: 3;
}

.child {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>7</h2>
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>lorem</div>
  <div class='child'>lorem</div>
  <div class='child'>lorem</div>
  <div class='child'>lorem</div>
  <div class='child'>lorem</div>
  <div class='child'>lorem</div>
  <div class='child'>lorem</div>
</div>
<h2>8</h2>
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>lorem</div>
  <div class='child'>lorem</div>
  <div class='child'>lorem</div>
  <div class='child'>lorem</div>
  <div class='child'>lorem</div>
  <div class='child'>lorem</div>
  <div class='child'>lorem</div>
  <div class='child'>lorem</div>
</div>
<h2>9</h2>
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>lorem</div>
  <div class='child'>lorem</div>
  <div class='child'>lorem</div>
  <div class='child'>lorem</div>
  <div class='child'>lorem</div>
  <div class='child'>lorem</div>
  <div class='child'>lorem</div>
  <div class='child'>lorem</div>
  <div class='child'>lorem</div>
</div>
```

### Example 2

Below is using the same basic concept as my first example, but it relies on the `.width()` and `.offset()` of elements. To allow for different heights of the children elements.

```js
$('.child').click(function() {
  let thisOffset = Math.floor($(this).offset().left - $(this).parent().offset().left); # subtract parent's offset from clicked element, to "zero" it
  let thisColumn = 0;
  let loopStop = false

  while (!loopStop) {
    thisColumn++;
    thisOffset -= $(this).width();

    if (thisOffset < 0) {
      loopStop = true;
    }
  }

  console.log(thisColumn);
});
```

```css
.parent {
  column-count: 3;
}

.child {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>7</h2>
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>lorem</div>
  <div class='child'>lorem</div>
  <div class='child'>lorem</div>
  <div class='child'>lorem</div>
  <div class='child'>lorem</div>
  <div class='child'>lorem</div>
  <div class='child'>lorem</div>
</div>
<h2>8</h2>
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>lorem</div>
  <div class='child'>lorem</div>
  <div class='child'>lorem</div>
  <div class='child'>lorem</div>
  <div class='child'>lorem</div>
  <div class='child'>lorem</div>
  <div class='child'>lorem</div>
  <div class='child'>lorem</div>
</div>
<h2>9</h2>
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>lorem</div>
  <div class='child'>lorem</div>
  <div class='child'>lorem</div>
  <div class='child'>lorem</div>
  <div class='child'>lorem</div>
  <div class='child'>lorem</div>
  <div class='child'>lorem</div>
  <div class='child'>lorem</div>
  <div class='child'>lorem</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that there always be three columns, you can do something like this:

```
$('.child').click(function() {
  let columnIndex = Math.floor($(this).index() / 3);
  console.log(columnIndex)
});
```

Comment: `parent` is responsive, i.e. it changes column count. Also  `child` have different height - there is no the equal number of them inside a column.

Comment: @puerto create codepen or jsfiddle with responsive example and share link so i (and other devs) could see full example. tnx

Answer (score 0):

With a bit of preprocessing, the relevant information can be gleaned from the bounding client rect of the `.child` widgets: we know that they are arranged in a rectangular grid, thus collecting the indexes  at which the `x` component of the bounding client rect changes suffices to identify the wrapover between columns.

In a responsive setting, the preprocessing would need to be called on viewport resizings and style changes affecting glyph sizes and layout dimensions, possibly when adding/deleting content.

This is the standalone code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
       .parent{
        column-count:3;
        }

        .child{
        cursor:pointer;
        }
        </style>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
    let map_idx2col = []
      , map_idx2rel = []
      , map_col2len = []
      ;

    $(document).ready( () => {
      let ccur      = 0
        , idxrel    = 0
        , xoff      = 0
        ;
      $(".parent > .child").each ( (idx, e) => {
          let bcr = e.getBoundingClientRect()
            ;

          if (bcr.x > xoff) {
              ccur++;
              map_col2len[ccur] = 0;
              idxrel = 0;
              xoff   = bcr.x;
          }
          map_idx2col[idx] = ccur;
          map_idx2rel[idx] = idxrel;
          idxrel++;
          map_col2len[ccur]++;
      });

      $('.child').click(function() {
          let abc = column(this)
            ;

          console.log(`
              column:       ${abc.column}
            , column size:  ${abc.size}
            , row:          ${abc.row}
          `);
//          let a = column(this);
//          let b = $(this).column().children().length;
//          let c = $(this).index(relative to a column);
      });
    }); // ready

    function column ( e ) {
        let idx = $(e).prevUntil(e, '.child').length
          ;

        return {
            column:     map_idx2col[idx]
          , row:        map_idx2col[idx]
          , size:       map_col2len[map_idx2col[idx]]
        };
    } // column
      </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="eh_onLoad()">
      <div class='parent'>
      <div class='child'>lorem</div>
      <div class='child'>lorem</div>
      <div class='child'>lorem</div>
      <div class='child'>lorem</div>
      <div class='child'>lorem</div>
      <div class='child'>lorem</div>
      <div class='child'>lorem</div>
      <div class='child'>lorem</div>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Demo**

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/collapsar/otgjb9x4/6/).

**Pro**

This solution will work even with css properties `orphans`/`widows` set, which enforce a minimum number of lines per column (until the layout algorithm runs out of data to layout,of course) - in this setting, solutions that deduce columns position mathematically from the `column-count` property only (assuming height-balanced columns) will fail!

**Con**

Will need modifications with css properties changing the horizontal position of `.child` elements if these properties` values change within a column.